# Testing component that uses helper function from diffrent file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, vitest

I'm trying to test a React component (Jest / Vitest). In this component, an imported function from another file is executed, which takes setState as an argument. Unfortunately, she doesn't change this piece. However, as a test, I moved this function to this file with the component and it works then. How to handle it so that the external one works ?

```
it("handles onClick", async () => {
  render(<BrowserRouter><LoginComponent /></BrowserRouter>);
  jest.spyOn(LoginComponent, "authValidation")
  const loginButton = screen.getByText("Log in");

  userEvent.click(loginButton);

  await waitFor(() => expect(mockedAuthValidator).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))
  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(/Text about no password and username/)).toBeInTheDocument())

  })
```

```
import { authValidator } from "../../utils/authValidator";
const [authValidationError, setAuthValidationError] = useState<string>("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!authValidator(user, setAuthValidationError)) {
      return;
    } etc.
```

I expect that function would works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mocking it using jest.mock and providing a mock implementation for it:

```
jest.mock("../../utils/authValidator", () => ({
  authValidator: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)
}));
```

```
const [authValidationError, setAuthValidationError] = useState<string>("");

useEffect(() => {
  authValidator(user, setAuthValidationError);
}, [user]);

const handleSubmit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // validation result will be stored in authValidationError state
  if (authValidationError) {
    return;
  } 
  // continue with form submission
};
```